# how to configure before Login URL for Grails Spring Security SAML Plugin

Tags: grails, wso2, saml

I'm using Grails Spring Security SAML 3.3.1 Plugin in my application.
I'm using WSO2 as my identity provider.

The setup is working fine. When *grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.active* is set to true and when I launch my application's web console (ex: http://localhost:8080/WebConsole/) it redirects to the WSO2 login page.

I believe the grails saml plugin takes care of this redirection to IDP login.

Is there any way I can configure this redirection URL ???
I want to redirect to my application web console and from there on clicking on SSO login it should redirect to WSO2 login.

Comment: Have you checked code or official docs of this plugin? Provide urls for both.

Comment: You need to configure the SP and IDP also along with that IDPCert file you have to generate where you need to change the security certificate for handshaking of IDP and SP. You can follow grails plugin for SAML

Comment: You may find this documentation helpful, based upon your Grails version you can go through. https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved it by removing SAML related filters** (samlEntryPoint, samlProcessingFilter, samlLogoutFilter, samlLogoutProcessingFilter) to my application's web console default login URL. Now I can access my application's default login page when SAML is active.

By default when SAML is active we were adding these filters as part of 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap' which was causing this redirection to the WSO2 login page.